# Do we have any way to set role to manual add user firebase console?

Tags: firebase

I build an application which storing data on cloud with NestJs. I want to add a user manually by login to firebase account and go to

**firebaes console => Authentication => Add User**.

I wonder how can I assign role to user which I added since I see only email & password?

Comment: What are you asking? You can add a user in the console as you mentioned - do you mean with a different type of authentication? What do you mean by 'role'?

Comment: Hey Sok Chanty. Did you get anywhere with this? Two people tried helping with an answer below. Did you have a chance to check that out and try them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users in Firebase Authentication have no concept of a role. Instead Firebase Authentication purely focuses on authenticating the users (allowing them to prove who they are), and leaves authorization (what they are allowed to do) to the application.

For a good way to implement role based security, have a look at the documentation on [Attribute-based and Role-based access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#attribute-based_and_role-based_access). This shows how to protect resources in Firebase's Firestore, Realtime Database, and Cloud Storage, as well as a link to how to set custom claims for the user's through the Admin SDKs. There is no option to set custom claims for a user through the console, but there is nowadays an experimental extension that allows you to [set custom claims through writing to Firestore](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/experimental-extensions/tree/next/firestore-auth-claims).

Comment: It is possible to set custom claims for a user through the console. See below

Comment: That screen is where you set the access permissions that collaborators have to your Firebase project. Users in this list unfortunately are not related to the Firebase Authentication users that use your apps.

Answer (score 1):

Project settings -> Users and permissions

[image]

Comment: This screen is where you set the access permissions that collaborators have to your Firebase project. Users in this list unfortunately are not related to the Firebase Authentication users that use your apps, which seems to be what OP is asking about.